# How to remove fisheye from videos on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I have some videos I have taken using a head-mounted video-camera.  The camera records the videos with a 'fisheye' effect.  How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried for ages, different solutions, taking me around all kinds of options, installing Shotcut, and so on.  In the end, what worked for me was:

- install the following:
   `sudo apt-get install pkg-config yasm frei0r-plugins cmake libfaac-dev libx264-dev opencl-headers`
- download latest frei0r zip from 
  https://github.com/ddennedy/frei0r/archive/master.zip
- unzip frei0r zip, cd inside, do:

  `cmake .`
  `make`
  `sudo make install`
- (at this point, I also downloaded and installed vidstab, from https://github.com/georgmartius/vid.stab/archive/master.zip )
- download ffmpeg source-code, from http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-2.3.3.tar.bz2
- untar, cd into the directory, run ./configure as follows:
  `./configure --enable-frei0r --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree`  (if you've installed vidstab, you can also add `--enable-libvidstab`, like I did)
  `make`
  `sudo make install`

Now, you can use frei0r:defish0r like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -strict -2 -i in.mov -vcodec libx264 -b:v 800k 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -vf frei0r=defish0r:0.75:y:0.6:0 -acodec copy out.mov
```

Comment: Another option is the [lenscorrection](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lenscorrection) filter which has recently been ported from frei0r on 12 Aug. It is a native FFmpeg filter, so it does not need any external libraries.

Comment: Yes, I fought with lenscorrection for a bit, but then found that defish0r did what I wanted really easily.  I've put the defish0r parameters that I used in the command above.  I never quite got lenscorrection to work for me.  Feel free of course to add an answer that shows how to use lenscorrection.

Comment: (@LordNeckbeard, by the way, thanks for your posting on vidstab, which was one of my best sources on information on getting ffmpeg working, and is where I got the vidstab build information above)

Comment: @LordNeckbeard But how do you apply that `lenscorrection` filter?

Comment: @ArekBulski I've never actually used it and I am unable to test now so I can only refer you to the [lenscorrection filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lenscorrection) and [Correct lens distortion with ffmpeg](http://video.stackexchange.com/q/14772/1760).